# why won't my pages stop caching?

Tags: html, caching, header, metadata, meta-tags

i am using this header (see below).
So why do my pages keep caching on IE???

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <META NAME="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" CONTENT="True">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="No-Cache">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="No-Cache,Must-Revalidate,No-Store">
 <META NAME="Robots" CONTENT="NoIndex,NoFollow">
 <META ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED!!!** Instead of .html or .htm use .php and use a php header like this one:

```
<?php
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: What do your HTTP headers look like?

Comment: what do you mean? the code is exactly as posted in the question details

Comment: That's the HTML code; the HTTP headers are metadata sent by the server before your content. I'm sure some browser plugins can show them to you, or you can use [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other suggestions try adding a dynamic value to the page request, that'll have a better chance of not caching.

(i.e. /foo.html?a=9585874034854 (or epoch or something else just as dynamic).

Also, your header needs: 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store

That tells the system don't cache it or even store it in cache.

Comment: i cant give a dynamic value to my page request, because i will need it for other purposes

Comment: also, [don't use querystring](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)